# Can I connect a line voltage wireless thermostat to a gas furnace?

Tags: electrical

I recently had my basement fully renovated and I realized after finishing it that the wires that connected my old thermostat were removed. I ordered a wireless thermostat and unfortunately I got a line voltage one and it seems there is not wireless low voltage thermostats out there in the market.

Comment: Please add pictures and model numbers. Have you read the manual  for your thermostat? Also exactly what is your question?

Comment: There are plenty of wireless low-voltage thermostats. The catch is that (a) there is a "base station" that will need to be wired - but that could be installed right next to the HVAC equipment, and (b) unless plugged in for power, a wireless thermostat will require periodic battery replacement.